# Parallel Resistor Calculation -- Higher Equivalent Resistance

Tags: resistors

\$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are in parallel. What should be the value of \$R_2\$ if \$R_1 = 100\Omega\$ and their equivalent resistance is \$1\text{k}\Omega\$?

Comment: value comes out to be negative ?

Comment: Putting resistors in parallel never gives you an equivalent resistance greater than either individual resistor. Just put two resistors in series to increase the equivalent resistance.

Comment: If I use one resistor to be 1K then other approaches infinity ?Explainable through mathematics , Yes but I cant digest this idea

Comment: -111.11\$\Omega\$. Impossible with real resistors, possible with some active circuit configurations.

Comment: I like this perspective , could you explain more

Answer (score 6):

Mathematically put:
$$R_1 || R_2=\frac{R_1 R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$
With your values:
$$1000=\frac{100 R_2}{100 + R_2}$$
Rearranging:$$
100000+1000R_2=100R_2$$
Or 
$$9R_2=-1000$$
So \$R_2=-111.11\Omega\$. Negative resistance.Physical? Not for a passive component such as resistor.

Comment: This is possible with active component ? How , just curious

Comment: Consider a voltage-controlled current source, such that will produce negative relation of V/I.

Comment: Would it be possible to acquire this negative resistance in a specific operating region of the tunnel diode (a passive component)?

Comment: It would be the dynamic resistance (dV/dI)

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to have that combination.

If you put two resistors in parallel, the combined resistance will be smaller.

Why? Well it's really quite simple. Imagine pumping water down a pipe. Now add a second pipe, is the amount of water you can get through going to increase or decrease? It will go up, because there is more space for water to flow through.

The same is true with resistors, if you add a second one, the same current will flow through the first resistor, but an additional current will flow through the second resistor. As \$V=I \times R\$ then if you increase the current that can flow then the overall resistance is going to go down.

Answer (score 4):

The calculation for a parallel Resistor R2 to put in series with a resistor R1 to get a desired resistance Rx is:

R2 = \$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{Rx} - \frac{1}{R1}}\$ = -111.11\$\Omega\$ in this case.

Here's an example of how such a result could be realized with an active circuit. First, let's assume that one end of the resistor is grounded (it makes it a lot easier).

We have a 100 ohm resistor to ground and we would like to put something in parallel with it that will make it look like a 1K resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFO8Bn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you simulate this circuit you will find that the voltage at R4 is 1.0V for 1mA in, and about 0V for 0mA. In other words it is behaving like a 1K resistor, so the active circuit is acting like a -111.1\$\Omega\$ resistor. This is a specific case of the [negative impedance converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_impedance_converter) circuit.

Comment: +1 Way to go above and beyond, but this is probably massive overkill for what can be accomplished with a \$900\Omega\$ resistor.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent resistance of a parallel combination is always less than the lowest resistance present.If you can reach your home from school via two different routes...the importance of any single of them would be less for you (if one is blocked,you can always take the other) than if there was only one route.Now imagine yourself as an electron and imagine the routes as resistor.Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have a 100 ohm resistor with 100 volts across it.  Then, by Ohm's law, you'll have:

$$ I = \frac{E}{R} = \frac{100V}{100\Omega} = \text{1 ampere} $$

of current through it.

But, instead of one ampere, let's say you need to take two amperes from the 100 volt supply.

Since one 100 ohm resistor takes 1 ampere, if you connect another 100 ohm resistor across the supply it'll take another ampere for the total required current of two amperes.

But what if, instead of two resistors, you wanted to use only one? In that case, we could go back to Ohm's law and solve for the value of that single resistor by writing:

$$ R = \frac{E}{I} = \frac{100V}{2A} = \text{50 ohms} $$

Then, since the two 100 ohm resistors in parallel and the single 50 ohm resistor take the same current from the 100 volt supply, the equivalent resistance of two 100 ohm resistors in parallel must be equal to the resistance of the single resistor, which is 50 ohms.

Mathematically, the total resistance of resistances in parallel is equal to the reciprocal of the sum of their reciprocals, or:

$$ Rt = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R3}+\frac{1}{Rn}} $$

or, for two resistors in parallel:

$$ Rt = \frac{R1 \times R2}{R1+R2} $$

So you can see that it's really impossible for the total resistance of resistors in parallel to be greater than the value of the smallest.